# how can i test php api in firebase.google.com

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working in php project to send pushnotification. I have signup and get api key at  https://console.firebase.google.com.  I have also get following code from some reference site.

```
/*  
Parameter Example
    $data = array('post_id'=>'12345','post_title'=>'A Blog post');
    $target = 'single tocken id or topic name';
    or
    $target = array('token1','token2','...'); // up to 1000 in one request
*/
function sendMessage($data,$target){
//FCM api URL
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
//api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
$server_key = 'AIzaSyBY5ZTQiCrFY6Syq9oymtlJODcwvkGyxmI';

$fields = array();
$fields['data'] = $data;
if(is_array($target)){
    $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
}else{
    $fields['to'] = $target;
}
//header with content_type api key
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
  'Authorization:key='.$server_key
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

But my query is that how can i use it ? i means how can i get target/token to test ? can i get this required token without android ? Is there any console where i can get test token for specific mobile. I want to test above code and so.

Answer (score -1):

In the application you will have a class that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService

Overwrites the following method and run the code

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    //Getting registration token
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    //Displaying token on logcat
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

}
```

it displays the token on the AndroidStudio console